# Saving Estimator models with least validation error and restoring for training

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-estimator

I would like to be able to save the Estimator model during training whenever the error decreases on the validation set and keep a certain number of these best performing models, in case something goes wrong during training (like overfitting).

The available options seem to be implementing a Hook, an Exporter or using the EstimatorSpecs returned by Estimator.evaluate. However:

- I can not use a Hook, since I need the mean loss on the whole validation set and Hooks are called after each step.
- With an exporter, I can export the model to the SavedModel format, but I can't seem to find anything about restoring the model from this format and continuing training, with an Estimator. Though, it seems to be possible with a session.
- The EstimatorSpecs returned also can't be used since I can't save the model with tf.train.Saver without the estimator's session.

Also, I believe the best validation error found so far should somehow be serialized on disk. This way, whenever I restore the model and resume training, the component responsible with saving the best models knows the best validation error found so far, so that instead of starting with a flag value and saving the first model as being 'the best', it continues from where it left off.

Is there a way I can achieve this?

Comment: Hi there, I have the same problem and can't solve it. Would you mind sharing the code to save the exporter, though?